# why the CCameraDS class can not open more than 3 cameras in the same time?

Tags: c++, opencv, directshow

As the opencv library does not provide function to open the specified camera,so i use the 
CCameraDS class implements with DirectShow. Unfortunately, when i open more than 3 cameras
in the same time, the program dead!!!what i do? Is that anyone like me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With multiple USB cameras you need to be aware of limited USB bandwidth - this is the most likely reason of unexpected video capture behavior. Make sure to search, this is a duplicate of over a dozen of similar questions.

Solution might be to reduce video resolution, frame rate, to use compressed capture formats, to attempt to use different hubs or just switch to non-USB hardware.